# Usually in my sentences

Tags: adverb-placement

By moving the word "usually" does its emphasis change?

1. "Usually I have dinner at 12." (Now I am having dinner at two)
2. "Usually I don't have dinner at two".
3. "I don't have dinner at two usually."
4. "I don't usually have dinner at two."
5. "I have dinner at 12 usually."
6. "I usually don't have dinner at two."

Comment: They're all fine, and I can't think of any difference in meaning. Idiomatically, I'm not particularly keen on having any significant "distance" between the verb *(**have**)* and the adverb that's modifying it *(**usually**)* - especially when the verb is being *negated*, so #3 would probably be "stylistically weak" in most contexts. There's probably a context where even #3 could be the "preferred" version, but we're talking about *very* fine points of style that wouldn't be agreed upon by everyone anyway.

Comment: Would it be wrong to say that I can emphasize "usually" in each of them to express that this isn't the usual time when I have dinner and in "I usually have dinner at 12"?

Comment: Yes, you can put heavy stress on ***usually*** in all your examples, always with the same implication (that the contrast between what you do and don't usually do is contextually very significant - almost certainly because ***at time of speaking, you're "breaking" the established pattern*** (i.e. - ***right now***, speaker is doing whatever is ***not*** "usual" for him).